# Primefaces: How can I create a popup list?

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I want to make a button that when is pressed will show a popup with a list of objects, from which I can select one to see it's details. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

Use [`<p:dialog>`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/dialog.jsf) to show a dialog by a button click. Then to select one of the items, use [`<p:dataTable>`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableRowSelectionInstant.jsf) (or any other `<p:dataXXX>` component).

Just peek through [their showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase) to see what's all available. It comes along with good code examples.

Answer (score 0):

It's a standard Swing component - called JPopUpMenu

Use the ActionListener interface on the JButton (I assume you are using Swing) to pop it up.

Good wishes, - M.S.

Oops, Sorry, I thought it was a Java question.... didnt read the jsf tag. Please ignore.

Answer (score 0):

you can use autocomplete to show the list and associate an event listener to show related infos on the selected value.